Using lex and bison together with swift from Xcode
I'm working on integrating Swift with a simple parser generated using lex and bison in an Xcode 16.1 project.
Below is my current code:
calc.l
%{
#include "calc.tab.h"
#include <stdlib.h>    
%}


%%
[0-9]+      { yylval.num = atoi(yytext); return NUMBER; }
[ \t\n]+    ;  
"+"         return '+';
"-"         return '-';
"*"         return '*';
"/"         return '/';
"("         return '(';
")"         return ')';
.           return yytext[0]; 
%%


calc.y
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "calc.h"

void yyerror(const char *s);  
int result;  
%}


%union {
    int num;
}

/* Define tokens with types */
%token <num> NUMBER
%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/'

/* Use %type to declare the type of non-terminal symbols */
%type <num> expr

%%
expr:
    expr '+' expr { $$ = $1 + $3; }
  | expr '-' expr { $$ = $1 - $3; }
  | expr '*' expr { $$ = $1 * $3; }
  | expr '/' expr { $$ = $1 / $3; }
  | '(' expr ')' { $$ = $2; }
  | NUMBER       { $$ = $1; }
  ;
%%

int main(void) {
    return yyparse();
}

void yyerror(const char *s) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", s);
}


calc.h
#ifndef CALC_H
#define CALC_H



extern int yylex(void);
extern int yyparse(void);
void yyerror(const char *s);
int parseExpression(void);

#endif


calc.c
#include "calc.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int result;

int parseExpression(void) {
    if (yyparse() == 0) {
        return result;
    } else {
        return -1; // Error
    }
}

void yyerror(const char *s) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", s);
}


Bridging-Header.h
#import "calc.h"

This is a simple SwiftUI view to call the parser:

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var result: Int32 = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(result)")
            
            Button("Calculate") {
                let expression = "3 + 5 * (10 - 4)"
                result = evaluate(expression: expression)
                print("Result: \(result)")
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
    
    
    func evaluate(expression: String) -> Int32 {
        
        expression.withCString { cString in
            freopen("/dev/stdin", "r", stdin)
            fputs(cString, stdin)
        }
        return parseExpression()
    }

}


And I manually run these commands from a terminal:
flex -o lex.yy.c calc.l 
bison -d calc.y -o calc.tab.c


When I compile the project in Xcode, I encounter the following error that I haven’t been able to resolve:

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_yywrap", referenced from:
      _yylex in lex.yy.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


Could anyone provide some guidance or point me in the right direction?

This question is similar to: Unable to compile output of lex. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Adding the %option noyywrap was not the solution. See my own answer below.

From what I see, you decided to keep %option noyywrap and it did help but then you've got another error, that seems unrelated to _yywrap. Remember that questions on Stack Overflow should focus on a single issue. I think you should ask another question about the other problem.

My question was not a duplication of an existing one and just adding the option:
%option noyywrap

as suggested did not resolve the issue. In fact, it introduced multiple errors due to duplicate variable and function definitions.
This was because including both .l (Flex) and .y (Bison) files in the Xcode project automatically triggers both Flex and Bison behind the scenes.
The solution was to update the tokenizer and parser definitions to avoid referencing calc.tab.h, which was not available.
Below are the final working files:
calc.l
%option noyywrap

%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum {
    NUMBER = 258,
    PLUS,
    MINUS,
    MULTIPLY,
    DIVIDE,
    LEFTPAR,
    RIGHTPAR
};
    
union YYSTYPE {
    int num;
};
    
extern union YYSTYPE yylval;
extern int expression_value;
extern void yyerror(const char *s);

%}


%%
[0-9]+      { yylval.num = atoi(yytext); return NUMBER; }
[ \t\n]+    ;
"+"         return PLUS;
"-"         return MINUS;
"*"         return MULTIPLY;
"/"         return DIVIDE;
"("         return LEFTPAR;
")"         return RIGHTPAR;
.           return yytext[0];
%%


calc.y
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void yyerror(const char *s);
int yylex(void);

int expression_value;

%}


%union {
    int num;
}

%token <num> NUMBER
%token PLUS
%token MINUS
%token MULTIPLY
%token DIVIDE
%token LEFTPAR
%token RIGHTPAR
%left PLUS MINUS
%left MULTIPLY DIVIDE

%type <num> expr

%%
    
input:
  |  expr { expression_value = $1; }
  ;
    
expr:
    expr PLUS expr  { $$ = $1 + $3; }
  | expr MINUS expr { $$ = $1 - $3; }
  | expr MULTIPLY expr { $$ = $1 * $3; }
  | expr DIVIDE expr { $$ = $1 / $3; }
  | LEFTPAR expr RIGHTPAR { $$ = $2; }
  | NUMBER       { $$ = $1; }
  ;
%%

void yyerror(const char *s) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", s);
}


calc.h
#ifndef CALC_H
#define CALC_H

int evaluate_expression(const char *expression, int *result);

#endif


calc.c
#include "calc.h"
#include <stdio.h>

extern int yyparse(void);
extern void yy_scan_string(const char *str);
extern void yylex_destroy(void);
extern int expression_value;

int evaluate_expression(const char *expression, int *result) {
    
    yy_scan_string(expression);

    // Parse and evaluate the expression
    int status = yyparse();

    yylex_destroy();
    
    if (status == 0) {
        *result = expression_value;
    }
    
    return  status;
}

This is the Swift(UI) code that call the parser:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var expression: String = ""
    @State var result: Int32?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextEditor(text: $expression)

            if let result {
                Text("\(result)")
            }

            Button("Calculate") {
                result = evaluate(expression: expression)
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }

    func evaluate(expression: String) -> Int32? {
        var result: Int32 = 0

        let status = expression.withCString { cString in
            evaluate_expression(UnsafeMutablePointer(mutating: cString), &result)
        }

        if status != 0 {
            // The parse returned an error
            return nil
        }

        return result
    }
}

Note that a Swift-Bridging.h file is required to call the evaluate_expression function.

I can't say I understand your explanation, maybe because I don't know swift nor xcode. However, looking at the new lex code, I can see that you're manually duplicating the list of yacc tokens in the lex source, which is a terrible practice.

Maybe you are right. Let me know how to fix that, though.

I don't know what error you've got and I don't know Swift to check. You should ask another question and aim for a minimal code required to reproduce the problem. (Because I have doubts that the swift part is even related to the issue.)

Have you read this: 'In fact, it introduced multiple errors due to duplicate variable and function definitions'? Please, provide specific suggestion to avoid manually duplicating the token definition, otherwise this solution is perfectly fine to me

"multiple errors due to duplicate variable and function definitions" doesn't tell me a lot. I would have to see specific errors. As for avoiding manually duplicating the token definitions, I don't know why you did it in the first place other than it solved your multiple definitions problem in some vague way.
